# Sketch the Region Bounded by Surfaces

Tags: plotting

I am presented with the following problem: Sketch the region bounded by the surfaces  $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $x^2+y^2=1$ for $1$ less than/equal to $z$ greater than/equal to $2$.

I am not sure how to go about plotting this. I have tried multiple different ways but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: You realize this is just the unit circle in the x-y plane translated by (0,0,1)? In any case note that [`RegionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html) requires a thickness to plot. If you'd like I can provide an answer where I show the shape using `RegionPlot3D`.

Comment: Its fine, because the dawggie wants the bound area between those planes, not the planes themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with the first area (since we are considering the bound area, we can use equalities). Change the equality depending on a closed or open interval.

```
RegionPlot3D[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < z, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

Bound it with the second

```
RegionPlot3D[
 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < z && x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4,
   4}]
```

[image]

And then the final z condition

```
RegionPlot3D[
 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < z && x^2 + y^2 < 1 && 1 <= z <= 2, {x, -4, 
  4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

And there you have it.

Comment: The two commands return a blank plot for me?
EDIT: All the commands return a blank plot :(

Comment: Can you post one command - also, what version of Mathematica :)